A question on Tikz keys
Using the code in this answer I sometimes need to change the fill color where it says white in the code: node[midway,sloped,fill=white,dim label]. What is the way to do that?
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta}
\newif\ifdrawdimlineleft
\newif\ifdrawdimlineright
\tikzset{dimlabel distance/.initial=5mm,
vertical lines extend/.initial=5mm,
vertical dim line/.style={gray,thin},
dim arrow line/.style={latex-latex,thin},
dim label/.style={},
left dimline/.is if=drawdimlineleft,
left dimline=true,
right dimline/.is if=drawdimlineright,
right dimline=true,
indicate dimensions/.style={decorate,decoration={
show path construction,
lineto code={
\draw[dim arrow line]
    ($ (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dimlabel distance}!-90:(\tikzinputsegmentlast) $) -- ($ (\tikzinputsegmentlast)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dimlabel distance}!90:(\tikzinputsegmentfirst) $)
 \ifx#1\empty
 \else
 node[midway,sloped,fill=white,dim label]{#1}%code here
 \fi;
\ifdrawdimlineleft
\draw[vertical dim line] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- 
($ (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vertical lines
extend}!-90:(\tikzinputsegmentlast) $);
\fi
\ifdrawdimlineright
\draw[vertical dim line]    (\tikzinputsegmentlast) -- 
    ($ (\tikzinputsegmentlast)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vertical lines extend}!90:(\tikzinputsegmentfirst) $); 
\fi 
}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
    plotmark/.style = {%
    draw, fill=red, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4pt
  }
]
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=basic]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,3);

    \draw[postaction={indicate dimensions={label}}] (A)--(B);

    \node[plotmark, label={above:$A$}] at (A) {};
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$B$}] at (B) {};
  \end{scope}
  \node at (basic.north) {basic application};   
  %
  \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,local bounding box=no left]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,3);
    \draw[postaction={indicate dimensions={label},left dimline=false}] (A)--(B);
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$A$}] at (A) {};
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$B$}] at (B) {};
  \end{scope}
  \node at (no left.north) {omit a vertical line};  
  %
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-6cm,local bounding box=no label]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,3);
    \draw[postaction={indicate dimensions=\empty}] (A)--(B);
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$A$}] at (A) {};
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$B$}] at (B) {};
  \end{scope}
  \node at (no label.north) {omit label};   
  %
  \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,yshift=-6cm,local bounding box=change arrow]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,3);
    \draw[postaction={indicate dimensions={label},
        dim arrow line/.style={Bar-Circle,thin}}] (A)--(B);
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$A$}] at (A) {};
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$B$}] at (B) {};
  \end{scope}
  \node at (change arrow.north) {change arrow appearance};  
  %
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-12cm,local bounding box=no line]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,3);
    \draw[postaction={indicate dimensions={label},dim arrow
    line/.style={opacity=0},dim label/.style={opacity=1}}] (A)--(B);
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$A$}] at (A) {};
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$B$}] at (B) {};
  \end{scope}
  \node at (no line.north) {omit arrow};    
  %
  \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,yshift=-12cm,local bounding box=no slope]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,3);
    \draw[postaction={indicate dimensions={label},
        dim label/.style={sloped=false}}] (A)--(B);
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$A$}] at (A) {};
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$B$}] at (B) {};
  \end{scope}
  \node at (no slope.north) {don't slope the label};    
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}


I would define and use a style. Codewise it’s like abbreviating into node[Abc] with Abc./style={…} e.g. in tikzset.

With my lack of knowledge on pgfkeys that is what tried; I just couldn't do it.

Suggestion: try if you can absorb your identical node statements by ine \newcommand with one parameter, which is the named coordinate, A or B in your case.

Did you highlight the relevant code parts? Don’t get your problem.

[dim label/.style={fill=blue},indicate dimensions={label}] instead of [indicate dimensions={label}] for blue rather than white. (untested) unless I'm missing something, I don't see you need another style here. you've already got one. (but maybe I missed somewhere else this gets used.)

Can you please edit your title to describe the actual problem you have? People can see that it is about pgfkeys in the tags and that it is a question is also implicit from posting it on a Q&A site.

@samcarter You are right. I thought about it, but was not sure what would be a good title.

@cfr, In light of your comment, I modified my answer, I had really complicated it. Thank you for helping me progress.

@pascal974 sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees. but sometimes, it's just a tree. ;)

New version. Much simpler, see cfr's comment.
Added for example dim label/.style={fill=red!10}} in the postaction
\draw[postaction={indicate dimensions={label},left dimline=false,dim label/.style={fill=red!10}}] (A)--(B);

code
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta}
\newif\ifdrawdimlineleft
\newif\ifdrawdimlineright
\tikzset{dimlabel distance/.initial=5mm,
vertical lines extend/.initial=5mm,
vertical dim line/.style={gray,thin},
dim arrow line/.style={latex-latex,thin},
dim label/.style={},
left dimline/.is if=drawdimlineleft,
left dimline=true,
right dimline/.is if=drawdimlineright,
right dimline=true,
indicate dimensions/.style={decorate,decoration={
show path construction,
lineto code={
\draw[dim arrow line]
    ($ (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dimlabel distance}!-90:(\tikzinputsegmentlast) $) -- ($ (\tikzinputsegmentlast)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dimlabel distance}!90:(\tikzinputsegmentfirst) $)
\ifx#1\empty
\else
node[midway,sloped,fill=white,dim label]{#1}%code here
\fi;
\ifdrawdimlineleft
\draw[vertical dim line] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- 
($ (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vertical lines
extend}!-90:(\tikzinputsegmentlast) $);
\fi
\ifdrawdimlineright
\draw[vertical dim line]    (\tikzinputsegmentlast) -- 
    ($ (\tikzinputsegmentlast)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vertical lines extend}!90:(\tikzinputsegmentfirst) $); 
\fi 
}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
    plotmark/.style = {%
    draw, fill=red, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4pt
}
]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=basic]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,3);

    \draw[postaction={indicate dimensions={label}}] (A)--(B);

    \node[plotmark, label={above:$A$}] at (A) {};
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$B$}] at (B) {};
\end{scope}
\node at (basic.north) {basic application};   
%
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,local bounding box=no left]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,3);
    \draw[postaction={indicate dimensions={label},left dimline=false,dim label/.style={fill=red!10}}] (A)--(B);
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$A$}] at (A) {};
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$B$}] at (B) {};
\end{scope}
\node at (no left.north) {omit a vertical line};  
%
\begin{scope}[yshift=-6cm,local bounding box=no label]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,3);
    \draw[postaction={indicate dimensions=\empty}] (A)--(B);
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$A$}] at (A) {};
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$B$}] at (B) {};
\end{scope}
\node at (no label.north) {omit label};   
%
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,yshift=-6cm,local bounding box=change arrow]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,3);
    \draw[postaction={indicate dimensions={label},
        dim arrow line/.style={Bar-Circle,thin},dim label/.style={fill=blue!10}}] (A)--(B);
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$A$}] at (A) {};
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$B$}] at (B) {};
\end{scope}
\node at (change arrow.north) {change arrow appearance};  
%
\begin{scope}[yshift=-12cm,local bounding box=no line]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,3);
    \draw[postaction={indicate dimensions={label},dim arrow
    line/.style={opacity=0},dim label/.style={opacity=1}}] (A)--(B);
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$A$}] at (A) {};
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$B$}] at (B) {};
\end{scope}
\node at (no line.north) {omit arrow};    
%
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,yshift=-12cm,local bounding box=no slope]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,3);
    \draw[postaction={indicate dimensions={label},
        dim label/.style={sloped=false}}] (A)--(B);
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$A$}] at (A) {};
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$B$}] at (B) {};
\end{scope}
\node at (no slope.north) {don't slope the label};    
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}


Old Version With indicate dimensions/.style args = {#1/#2} and node[midway,sloped,fill=\ifx&#2&white\else#2\fi,dim label]{#1}
if there is no second argument, fill in white
In the document

indicate dimensions={label/}} for white

indicate dimensions={label/blue!10} for blue!10


Code
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta}
\newif\ifdrawdimlineleft
\newif\ifdrawdimlineright
\tikzset{
  dimlabel distance/.initial=5mm,
  vertical lines extend/.initial=5mm,
  vertical dim line/.style={gray,thin},
  dim arrow line/.style={latex-latex,thin},
  dim label/.style={},
  left dimline/.is if=drawdimlineleft,
  left dimline=true,
  right dimline/.is if=drawdimlineright,
  right dimline=true,
  indicate dimensions/.style args = {#1/#2}{decorate,decoration={
  show path construction,
  lineto code={
    \draw[dim arrow line]
        ($ (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dimlabel distance}!-90:(\tikzinputsegmentlast) $) -- ($ (\tikzinputsegmentlast)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dimlabel distance}!90:(\tikzinputsegmentfirst) $)
    \ifx#1\empty
    \else
      node[midway,sloped,fill=\ifx&#2&white\else#2\fi,dim label]{#1}
    \fi;
    \ifdrawdimlineleft
      \draw[vertical dim line] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- 
      ($ (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vertical lines
      extend}!-90:(\tikzinputsegmentlast) $);
      \fi
  \ifdrawdimlineright
    \draw[vertical dim line]    (\tikzinputsegmentlast) -- 
        ($ (\tikzinputsegmentlast)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vertical lines extend}!90:(\tikzinputsegmentfirst) $); 
    \fi 
  }}}   
  }
  

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
    plotmark/.style = {%
    draw, fill=red, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4pt
  }
]
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=basic]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,3);

    \draw[postaction={indicate dimensions={label/}}] (A)--(B);

    \node[plotmark, label={above:$A$}] at (A) {};
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$B$}] at (B) {};
  \end{scope}
  \node at (basic.north) {basic application};   
  %
  \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,local bounding box=no left]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,3);
    \draw[postaction={indicate dimensions={label/blue!10},left dimline=false}] (A)--(B);
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$A$}] at (A) {};
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$B$}] at (B) {};
  \end{scope}
  \node at (no left.north) {omit a vertical line};  
  %
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-6cm,local bounding box=no label]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,3);
    \draw[postaction={indicate dimensions=\empty/}] (A)--(B);
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$A$}] at (A) {};
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$B$}] at (B) {};
  \end{scope}
  \node at (no label.north) {omit label};   
  %
  \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,yshift=-6cm,local bounding box=change arrow]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,3);
    \draw[postaction={indicate dimensions={label/red!10},
        dim arrow line/.style={Bar-Circle,thin}}] (A)--(B);
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$A$}] at (A) {};
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$B$}] at (B) {};
  \end{scope}
  \node at (change arrow.north) {change arrow appearance};  
  %
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-12cm,local bounding box=no line]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,3);
    \draw[postaction={indicate dimensions={label/},dim arrow
    line/.style={opacity=0},dim label/.style={opacity=1}}] (A)--(B);
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$A$}] at (A) {};
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$B$}] at (B) {};
  \end{scope}
  \node at (no line.north) {omit arrow};    
  %
  \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,yshift=-12cm,local bounding box=no slope]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,3);
    \draw[postaction={indicate dimensions={label/red},
        dim label/.style={sloped=false}}] (A)--(B);
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$A$}] at (A) {};
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$B$}] at (B) {};
  \end{scope}
  \node at (no slope.north) {don't slope the label};    
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}


Isn't there another way to approach it? The way it is, it seems it breaks the previous code. Isn't there a way, for example, like: default being white; and otherwise, say, label fill=red. In your code, we need to enter something even if there is no label; and after the label you need to put a / which is not intuitive.

cfr gave the correct answer
